# EWS error ErrorNoRespondingCASInDestinationSite

Tags: exchangewebservices

m having an issue with Office 365 EWS (its only Office 365, Exchange 2010 and 2013 work fine).  I can create my pull subscription without error but when I go to use it by calling

```
getEvents()
```

I receive an error:

> ErrorNoRespondingCASInDestinationSite
>
> The following error occured while retrieving events for exchange
>   resource:  - Exchange Web Services are not currently
>   available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers
>   in the destination site could process the request.

Here is some code snippets

Using autodiscover and setting up credentials

```
this.exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.Username, this.Password);
                    try {
                        this.exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(this.Username, RedirectionCallback);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.WriteToEventLog(EventLogEntryType.Warning, 104, "ExchangeDataAccess, AutodiscoverURL error: " + ex.Message);
                    }

                    if (exchangeService.Url == null)
                    {
                        this.ExchangeServerURL = GetOffice365EWSUrl(this.Username);
                        this.exchangeService.Url = new Uri(this.ExchangeServerURL);
                        this.exchangeService.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    }
```

Afterwhich we Login and find our exchange user that we will perform all operations under

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender1, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

                string username = this.Username;
                if (this.authenticateContext.GetExchangeServerVersion().Contains("365"))
                {
                    username = this.Username.Remove(this.Username.IndexOf("@"));
                }

                NameResolutionCollection resolveNameResult = this.exchangeService.ResolveName(username, ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsThenDirectory, true);

                if (resolveNameResult.Count() > 0)
                {
                    roomEmailAddress = resolveNameResult[0].Mailbox.Address;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roomEmailAddress))
                    {
                        this.ExchangeUserEmailAddress = roomEmailAddress;
                        logMsg.AppendLine("Logged into Exchange with " + roomEmailAddress + " successfully, RetrieveRoomsList is next");
                    }
                }
```

We then get a SubscribeResponse and save it to a list

```
                subscribeResponse = this.exchangeDataAccess.ExchangeSubscribe(syncPoint.ThirdPartyId, syncPoint.Watermark, true);
```

We pass the above object into a wrapper method to get all Events from the EWS

```
        Dictionary<PullSubscription, IEnumerable<ItemEvent>> mailboxEvents = null;

        GetEventsResults eventsResults = subscription.GetEvents();

        if (eventsResults == null || eventsResults.ItemEvents.Count() == 0) {
            return mailboxEvents;
        }

        mailboxEvents = new Dictionary<PullSubscription, IEnumerable<ItemEvent>>();
        mailboxEvents.Add(subscription, eventsResults.ItemEvents);
        return mailboxEvents;
```

The line that calls `subscription.GetEvents()` is where the exception indicated at the top is returned.
There is another layer of complexity added on because our Exchange user has a domain name of @FOOlab.onmicrosoft.com where as all of the rooms being managed have a domain name of @LAB.FOO.COM

According to the customer this is ADFS authentication, however I really don't know much about it.

I can say however that this code base did work (got events) and then something seemed to change and the error started popping up.  Originally I thought the customer changed something but we have tested this against another Office 365 (without ADFS) and saw the same error, so now I don't know what to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links below can explain it far better then I can, but what I have done so far which has resolved my issue is to surround the GetEvents
with the add and removal of the header data `X-AnchorMailbox`
MSDN [Link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx) [Link2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2990048/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0)

```
public Dictionary<PullSubscription, IEnumerable<ItemEvent>> GetEvents(SyncPoint syncpoint)
        {
            Dictionary<PullSubscription, IEnumerable<ItemEvent>> mailboxEvents = null; 

            if (this.authenticateContext.GetExchangeServerVersion().Contains("365"))
            {
                try
                {
                    //this is to maintain affinity (see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx)
                    //it was added to fix an error: The following error occured while retrieving events for exchange resource: <room address> - Exchange Web Services are not currently available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the request.
                    //according to docs it is only when getting notifications that its important
                    if (this.exchangeService.HttpHeaders.Any(m => m.Key.Equals("X-AnchorMailbox")))
                    {
                        this.exchangeService.HttpHeaders.Remove("X-AnchorMailbox");
                    }
                    this.exchangeService.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", syncpoint.ThirdPartyId); //this is the email address of the mailbox being queried
                }
                catch { }
            }

            GetEventsResults eventsResults = syncpoint.pullSubscription.GetEvents();

            if (eventsResults == null || eventsResults.ItemEvents.Count() == 0)
            {
                return mailboxEvents;
            }

            mailboxEvents = new Dictionary<PullSubscription, IEnumerable<ItemEvent>>();
            mailboxEvents.Add(syncpoint.pullSubscription, eventsResults.ItemEvents);

            try
            {
                this.exchangeService.HttpHeaders.Remove("X-AnchorMailbox");
            } catch { }

            return mailboxEvents;
        }
```